# How to test $scope.watch() used in custom directive's link function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine-jquery

I am trying to unit test a custom directive which uses `$scope.$watch` to capture any changes done to its attribute value.

[jsfiddle for the directive is here](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4813/)

Jasmin test case code :

```
it('should capture changes to color attribute', function() {
     var htmlElement = $compile('<div data-my-directive data-color="{color:blue}"></div>')($rootScope);
     expect(htmlElement).toHaveAttr('style', 'color:blue');
     //Now I want to change the color value of this htmlElement so $scope.watch comes into picture
});
```

If you refer the test case code, I am setting up initial value of `data-color` attribute and compiling it as htmlElement. 
Now how do I change the same element's `data-color` attribute so `$scope.$watch` picks up the change and new value gets assigned to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hard-coding the value of the attribute in your template, initialize it to a value coming from the scope:

```
data-color="someValue"
```

and

```
$rootScope.someValue = {color: 'blue'};
```

Then change the value of this object in the scope:

```
$rootScope.someValue = {'color': 'black'};
$rootScope.$apply();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use observe instead:

```
attributes.$observe('color', function(color){
    // convert string to object
    color = scope.$eval(color);
});
```

or use scope in directive:

```
scope: {
    color: '=color'
},
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
    scope.$watch('color', function(color){
        // you get color object here
    });
}
```